# Installing bootloader (GRUB) on a logical partitions?

Tags: linux, grub, bootloader

Is it possible to install GRUB on a logical partition? The partition is just 200 to 400 MB space?

Comment: You would better ask this question on http://serverfault.com/

Comment: Why serverfault? It's a question related to GrUB, so not only (or primarily) concerned to server and/or networking. I think this (SuperUser) is a good place to ask that.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, and I prefer to install Grub to a partition and not the MBR especially on multi-boot computers.

You will, however, need to make sure that the MBR code can boot a logical partition. As far as I remember, the MBR code that openSuse installs will do what you want (ie it just goes through the list of partitions until it finds one marked active then boots from it) but the MBR code that Microsoft uses will not (it will only boot from a partition if it is one of the four primary partitions and is the only partition marked active).

(If you are wanting to add Grub as an option in the Windows boot menu, then it is fine to use a logical partition as somewhere to install Grub in order to take an image.)

Answer (score 0):

short answer: Yes.

long answer: It depends on what kind of partition scheme/installation you have in mind, since the MBR must be in the first sector of the drive, or it can't boot up your system (assuming you don't want to boot using a floppy boot).

Here you'll find some useful informations: http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/

Hope that helps,
Regards